# Cannot add or update a child row: foreign key constraint fails

Tags: mysql, sql, foreign-keys

Hi I am wondering why I getting an error

> ERROR 1452 (23000): Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key
>   constraint fails (`exams`.`entries`, CONSTRAINT `entries_ibfk_2`
>   FOREIGN KEY (`student_id`) REFERENCES `students` (`student_id`))

Any help would be appriatiated!

Here are the scripts that I think are relevant to the problem I'm having,

First I made this table entries and everything was fine

```
CREATE TABLE entries(
subject_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
subject_name VARCHAR(60) NOT NULL,
level_of_entry VARCHAR(60) NOT NULL,
exam_board VARCHAR(60) NOT NULL,
student_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
date_of_exam DATETIME NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (date_of_exam),
FOREIGN KEY (subject_id)
REFERENCES subjects(subject_id),
FOREIGN KEY (student_id)
REFERENCES students(student_id)
```

Then I tried to insert data and I got the error.

```
INSERT INTO entries (subject_id,subject_name, level_of_entry, exam_board,date_of_exam)
VALUE ('1','chemistry','as','ocr','2017-05-05 12:00:00'),
('2','biology','gcse','aqa','2017-05-05 12:00:01'),
('3','music','gcse','edexcel','2017-05-05 12:00:02'),
('4','english','a','ocr','2017-05-05 12:00:03'),
('5','physics','a','aqa','2017-05-05 12:00:04'),
('6','maths','gcse','aqa','2017-05-05 12:00:05'),
('7','computing','gcse','aqa','2017-05-05 12:00:06'),
('8','physical_education','gcse','aqa','2017-05-05 12:00:07'),
('9','design_and_technology','gcse','aqa','2017-05-05 12:00:08'),
('10','french','gcse','aqa','2017-05-05 12:00:09');
```

It suggest on other questions similar to this to make sure your parent table has the same values but it does and its making know sense to me.
Here is the parent script.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS students(
student_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
first_name VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
middle_name VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
last_name VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
email VARCHAR(60) NOT NULL,
password CHAR(40) NOT NULL,
reg_date DATETIME NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (student_id) ,
UNIQUE (email));
```

Here is the other parent script but I'm having no problems with it.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS subjects(
subject_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
subject_name VARCHAR(60) NOT NULL,
level_of_entry VARCHAR(60) NOT NULL,
exam_board VARCHAR(60) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (subject_id) ,
UNIQUE (subject_id));
```

If anyone could help I would be extremely grateful!

Comment: mysql or sql-server?

Comment: where is `student_id` in your `insert` statement? You are not inserting a value which is defined as `not null`

Comment: I see you kept it as Auto Increment in `entries` table; a foreign key can never have auto increment value; this has to be defined in your `students` only.  Remove auto increment from `entries` table

Comment: first of all, you are inserting a nvarchar '1' into   an subject_id  int field.

Comment: Downvote for stupid title (corrected).

Answer (score 1):

There are two issues with your logic related to `student_id`.

> 1. You should not have `AUTO_INCREMENT` in foreign key table.

A table which has a foreign key can't auto-populate values (logically and technically). It has to refer to some value in its Primary table. In your case, it is `students` table.

So, change your table structure as below:

```
CREATE TABLE entries(
subject_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
subject_name VARCHAR(60) NOT NULL,
level_of_entry VARCHAR(60) NOT NULL,
exam_board VARCHAR(60) NOT NULL,
student_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
date_of_exam DATETIME NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (date_of_exam),
FOREIGN KEY (subject_id)
REFERENCES subjects(subject_id),
FOREIGN KEY (student_id)
REFERENCES students(student_id)
```

> 2. You should specify a value in your `INSERT` query for `entries` table

You need to ensure you insert a value manually in your `entries` table for `student_id` column.

A side not as specified in comments that you defined `subject_id` as `INT` but you are trying to insert character values.

Change your insert query as below:

```
INSERT INTO entries (subject_id,subject_name, level_of_entry, exam_board,date_of_exam, student_id)
VALUE (1,'chemistry','as','ocr','2017-05-05 12:00:00', 100),
(2,'biology','gcse','aqa','2017-05-05 12:00:01', 101);
```

*Note: I assumed 100 and 101 as your existing student ids from students table.  You need to replace them with the correct ids from your table.*